# rewrite get parameters in .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here is my website : `http://www.example.com`
and i want to rewrite url in .htaccess
here is URL :
`http://www.example.com/sub_portfolio.php?act=sub_cat`
and i want to ..

`/sub_portfolio/sub_cat`

i tried many rewrite condition it not worked and also check many post in our website stack overflow.
like url rewrite conditions

give suggetion...

Answer (score 1):

You can easily rewrite your url using the following code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sub_portfolio/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ sub_cat.php?act=$1 [NC,L]
```

*Make sure you place this code in your .htaccess file which should located in the same folder*

Hope that helps

Comment: I have tested that code and it is correct so I would suggest that you check to see if your htaccess file is actually being read. What server OS are you using? Also maybe try just a simple htaccess password protection to see if that works.