# Remove ?variable_name= from url while working with query string in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am Working At Codeigniter PHP.
And Trying To Pass Some Data From View To Controller With The The Help Of Query String, As I Don't Use Any Form.

As Following:

```
<a href="welcome/movie?name=<?php echo $popmovies->movie_name;?>" >GO</a>
```

But Through Query String My URL Is Looking So Garbage Type.
This Is What I Currently Have.

```
http://subs.nexthon.com/welcome/movie?name=Avangers
```

This Is What I Want To Have

```
http://subs.nexthon.com/welcome/movie/Avangers
```

How Can I Do This.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rewrite get parameters in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122936/rewrite-get-parameters-in-htaccess)

Answer (score 1):

Your anchor should be like this :

```
<a href="<?=site_url('welcome/movie/'.$popmovies->movie_name);?>" >GO</a>
```

Access like this in controller :

```
public function movie($movie_name)
{
   echo $movie_name;
   /*output : Avangers*/
}
```

for more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#passing-uri-segments-to-your-methods

Comment: Even easier is echo anchor("welcome/movie", $popmovies->movie_name)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly pass your data in URL

EXAMPLE FROM CODEIGNITER DOC

```
http://example.com/news/local/metro/crime_is_up
```

The segment numbers would be this:

1.news
2.local
3.metro
4.crime_is_up

You can get data by using segment()

```
$product_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

For mode detail please read [Codeigniter URL](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html)